# Converting gradient image to css properties

Tags: css

I need to convert this image into a css. I tried to use online tools with no success. 
Any suggestions?

Image:

[image]

Comment: U tried http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ ?

Comment: Yes, but I get image with just one color, not a gradient.

Comment: This tool seems be promising http://gradientfinder.com/

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a radial gradient using CSS?

Comment: Yes, exactly like in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 170px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, #00517D, #004367);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, #00517D, #004367);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, #00517D, #004367);
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #00517D, #004367);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://gradientfinder.com/ - Image gradient to css converter online

Your css for particular image

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(339deg, rgb(5, 68, 99) 0%, rgb(5, 68, 99) 97%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(339deg, rgb(5, 68, 99) 0%, rgb(5, 68, 99) 97%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(339deg, rgb(5, 68, 99) 0%, rgb(5, 68, 99) 97%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(339deg, rgb(5, 68, 99) 0%, rgb(5, 68, 99) 97%);
background: linear-gradient(111deg, rgb(5, 68, 99) 0%, rgb(5, 68, 99) 97%);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't working. I can't see the gradient, all the background have the same color.

Comment: @user3355028 It can't lie :/ your image doesn't differs much in terms of gradation, try with an more variate gradient

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this image for background... maybe? You can try `css gradient`.

```
#gradient {
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient((rgb(25, 85, 124), rgb(19, 68, 99)); /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-radial-gradient((rgb(25, 85, 124), rgb(19, 68, 99)); /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient((rgb(25, 85, 124), rgb(19, 68, 99)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: radial-gradient((rgb(25, 85, 124), rgb(19, 68, 99)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Color values are adjusted to fit your image